# Converting big endian structures to little endian

Tags: c, networking, endianness

I'm making a C program that communicates with a patient monitor that uses big endian byte ordering. For example, if I've certain C structure

```
typedef struct {
   int short a;
   int short b;
   int       c;
} msg;
```

To read this kind of structure, I can simply use ntohs(msg.a), ntohs(msg.b), ntohl(msg.c). But some of the structure has a buffer of short integers but that buffer itself is type of an another structure. For example,

```
typedef struct {
   int short length;
   int short b[MAX_BUF_SIZE];
} msg1;
```

The field "b" in above structure represents an another structure, which is below:

```
typedef struct {
   int short a;
   int short b;
} msg2;
```

Now, my question is 1) should I convert all the short integers of structure "msg1" to host order and then cast it to pointer of type "msg2" and simply read "msg2.a" and "msg2.b" or 2) I should convert the byte ordering of "msg2.a" and "msg2.b" as well or 3) just cast 
"msg1.b" to pointer of type "msg2" and read "msg2.a" and "msg2.b" by converting each of them to host order?

Please tell which one of the approach is correct to read msg1

### APPROACH 1

```
int t[msg1.length];
for(int i = 0; i < msg1.length; i++)
   t[i] = ntohs(*(msg1.b + i));
msg2 * msg2_m = (msg2 *)t;
/* should I convert the msg2_m.a and msg2_m.b as well? */
printf("%d:%d", msg2_m.a, msg2_m.b);
```

### APPROACH 2

All same except

```
printf("%d:%d", ntohs(msg2_m.a), ntohs(msg2_m.b));
```

### APPROACH 3

Not converting "msg1.b" and directly casting "msg1.b" to "msg2" and just convert "msg2.a" and "msg2.b" to host order.

```
msg2 *msg2_m = (msg2 *)msg1.a;
printf("%d:%d", ntohs(msg2_m.a), ntohs(msg2_m.b));
```

I need to understand when a structure is casted to some other structures does its byte ordering are changed according to the new structure when passed across network? I think APPROACH 3 is correct, but thats just me, I'm not sure about internals of byte ordering. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Shivam Kalra

Comment: Correct is the opposite of what you are doing on the sender. So what are you doing over there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, casting does not affect byte order.

Second, you don't want to be thinking about byte order everywhere in your code because you or someone else *will* forget and make a mistake somewhere and it will be hell trying to find the bug later.  So, as soon as you read the data in, convert it to the correct byte order.  If you read a struct in that contains an array of shorts, convert the whole array of shorts to the correct byte order immediately.  The same goes for any other structs.  Convert the data and store the result; don't just use ntohs each time you need to read or print something.  Segregate this code from the rest of your program so that you can forget about byte order in the other parts of the program and only think about byte order when you're dealing with the conversion code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What are the approaches to change the endianess without using ntoh.. functions?

Comment: @ShivamKalra: What platform are you using? Most platforms have specific macros or functions to help with this. And yes, you should conceptually not use the NTOHL family unless you're actually dealing with a network protocol.

Comment: [swab()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/swab.html) is one way.  But I wasn't trying to discourage you from using ntoh*, I just wanted to emphasize the importance of doing the conversion once and storing the result, instead of sprinkling conversion calls all over your code.  ntoh* allow your code to keeping working should it ever be recompiled to run on big-endian hardware; that is a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's usually better not to try to read or write `struct`s directly.  Instead, you should explicitly define your wire format and write your struct byte-by-byte to that (and then do the reverse when reading).  For example, to write:

```
typedef struct {
   short int a;
   short int b;
   int       c;
} msg;
```

you can do:

```
void WriteBigEndian16(uint16_t x, FILE* fp)
{
   fputc((x >> 8) & 0xFF, fp);
   fputc( x       & 0xFF, fp);
}

void WriteBigEndian32(uint32_t x, FILE* fp)
{
   fputc((x >> 24) & 0xFF, fp);
   fputc((x >> 16) & 0xFF, fp);
   fputc((x >>  8) & 0xFF, fp);
   fputc( x        & 0xFF, fp);
}

FILE* fp = fopen(...);
msg m; // Assume that this is initialized.
WriteBigEndian16(m.a, fp);
WriteBigEndian16(m.b, fp);
WriteBigEndian32(m.c, fp);
```

This has the advantages of:

- The code is endian-agnostic.  It doesn't matter if you're running on a little-endian machine or a big-endian machine.  You don't need to know.
- You avoid any confusion about whether your in-memory `struct`s are byte-swapped or not.  They will always be whatever the platform's native ordering is.
- You're defining the sizes of your fields too.  If you don't define your wire format, not only are you prone to endian mismatches, but you're prone to size mismatches too.  Who says that the two endpoints both use the same size for `int`?